# Flutter: DragTarget inside scrollable doesn't emit onLeave

Tags: flutter, scrollview, draggable, desktop

I'm using flutter on desktop with a mouse.

I put `DragTarget` inside scrollable `ListView`, and:

1. press left button on `Draggable`
2. drag the `Draggable` on top of `DragTarget`, `onMove` called, which is correct.
3. scroll mouse wheel while not moving the pointer, until `DragTarget` is scrolled out of pointer, `onLeave` not called, which is not expected.

`ListView` fixed, move the mouse, `onMove` and `onLeave` works fine.

Scroll the `ListView`, mouse fixed, `onMove` and `onLeave` doesn't fire.

How can I make `DragTarget` work inside scrollable?

---

sample code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const TestWindow());
}

class TestWindow extends StatelessWidget {
  const TestWindow({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => MaterialApp(
    title: 'test dragtarget',
    theme: ThemeData(
      useMaterial3: true,
      colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSeed(seedColor: Colors.green),
    ),
    debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
    home: Scaffold(body: _buildBody()),
  );

  Widget _buildBody() => ListView(
    children: [
      Draggable<int>(
        data: 100,
        feedback: Container(
          width: 200,
          height: 100,
          color: Colors.purple,
        ),
        child: Container(
          height: 100,
          color: Colors.red,
        ),
      ),
      DragTarget(
        onMove: (DragTargetDetails<int> details) {
          print('moving at ${details.offset}');
        },
        onLeave: (_) {
          print('left target');
        },
        builder: (BuildContext context, List<dynamic> accepts, List<dynamic> rejects) => Container(
          height: 200,
          color: Colors.green,
        ),
      ),
      Container(
        height: 300,
        color: Colors.yellow,
      ),
    ],
  );
}
```